# Google Sheets - Query - Running Total below dynamic results

Tags: google-sheets, formula, fibonacci

[Testing Sheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10TaO8jmFH563gb4KwCyUQtHxSfadunhWC-ZvTlNbOnQ/edit?usp=sharing)

> Wondering if there is a witty way to add a Total to the last row +1 of
>   a Query result.
>
> See Sheet 'Lookup' for a static example of what I am asking for.
>
> I don't know if there is a way to have a hidden column that calculates
>   transposed only under the last row of a query, or if there is a smart
>   way to work Query for this answer.

All great answers. Each on very useful in its use case.

Макс Махров gets the answer with using a query statement.

Now I was not keen on having an extra sheet to hold the totals so I added a row at the top which I can simply hide and used this formula:

```
query({Orders!A:E;A1:E1},"select Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col2 = '"&C3&"' order by Col4",1)
```

Only problem I have is trying to figure out how to add TEXT to the bottom row, it seems to only want numerical input.

How do I fix this?  What am I glitching?

Thanks !

Mars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to make second query and count totals for selected product.

Plan of actions:

1. add new sheet with query on it, something like this: `=QUERY(Orders!A:E,"select B, 0, sum(D) where B like '"&Lookup!C2&"' Group by B",0)`
2. Prepare arrayformula which combines data in Lookup sheet: `= ArrayFormula({Importrange(1),Importrange(2)})` Note that number of columns must retain the same.
3. Edit query so it takes `Col1, Col2, Col3...` instead of `A, B, C...`
4. Make word 'total' visible instead of zero. Set number format: `0;0;total` Set it for range B9:B on Lookup sheet
5. Make Conditional Formatting with formula `=and($B4 =0,isnumber($B4))` for range A4:C on Lookup sheet.

That's seems have to complete the task.

Hope it Helps!

[Your Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Xf2F7MiFL4eRxgWuZ940-0XGHYe-Y2KInXJ7SpzPBg/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Result]

Comment: This works, no doubt about it.  Let me ponder this a bit longer.  I want to make sure there is not a more elegant way.  Thank you for the ideas here, I may find a use for your involved formula/sheet juggling.  Cheers!

Comment: Yours is the best answer.  I added a row above my sum table which I can then Hide, used this query: query({Orders!A:E;A1:E1},"select Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col2 = '"&C3&"' order by Col4",1) but am confused as to why I can not get "Total" to show up?

Comment: I geuss, you get only numeric results. It's because QUERY formula automatically determine data type as numeric, so it can't return text. If so, you could type 0 instead of word 'total', and then make number format `0;0;total`, which means numeric for positive and negative, word "total" for zero.

Comment: Thank you, Great Help. Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LhYR0zmhjp1rHWtU7EwFEO9O6rCh51qaGXqHw0m3oEk/edit?usp=sharing).

Here is one way:

1. Put TOTAL way down in row 1000
2. Select the range A3:C999. Select <kbd>data</kbd> > <kbd>filter</kbd> to create filters
3. Select C3, set the filter to hide all blanks

A second way is to limit the query result to show only the top 8 results:

1. Change your query to `=query(Orders!A:E, "select A, C, D where B = '"&C2&"' order by D desc limit 8",1)` It will reverse-order column D (largest first), and set row limit to 8.
2. Change the formula of your TOTAL to `=sumif(Orders!B:B,C2,Orders!D:D)`

Comment: Nice tricks.  These would work fine in two specific cases.  1. There is no more data on the sheet to the right or left of the "lookup" query.  2.  Limiting the query result to a limit meets a specific requirement, ie Top 10 results.   Thank you for the answers, I am sure they will aid someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in the column adjacent to your query:

```
=ArrayFormula({$C$4:offset($C$4,count($C$4:$C),0,1,1);sum($C$4:offset($C$4,count($C$4:$C),0,1,1))})
```

It duplicates your column of values (I haven't figured out a way around that yet) and then adds a total to the bottom of that column, and changes dynamically with the range from your query.

[Here's a working version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18o-uw0u2OU3BFH818tQVPO8jBSvI0vN_VbgxLTGE-tI/edit?usp=sharing).

Interesting challenge! It got the old grey matter turning... ;)

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Nice Work! I like this, fairly simple and very useful when using an Arrayformula.  Will certainly keep this in my pocket! Thanks!